# Насколько популярен python в сфере настольных приложений?

Tags: python

Принято считать, что python - веб-язык или язык для маленьких прикладных скриптов. 
Интересно знать есть ли проекты, которые используют python как основной язык. 
Стали бы вы писать программу на python?

Comment: игры используют питон к примеру, даже крупные (World of tanks например, часть функционала на питоне написана, интерфейс на Scaleform flash, сам движок на с++ ИМНИП)

Comment: В сфере коммерческого софта питон не слишком популярен, поскольку исходный код достаточно трудно скрыть ))) Для написания открытого ПО - довольно популярен, особенно в никсах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Куча программ написаны на python. Что сразу вспомнилось:

- Deluge - torrent клиент
- Gajim - jabber клиент
- ranger - файловый менеджер
- mirage - просмотр изображений
- Wicd - утилита подключения к wifi

Так же на питоне пишутся плагины в таких программах как Gimp, Blender, Inscape

Comment: Ну иногда пишутся на Питоне, потом переписываются на что-то более шустрое (C++). Но вообще программ на Питоне много (один twisted чего стоит. А уж то, что на нём написано...)

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox):

> Both the Dropbox server and desktop
> client software are primarily written
> in Python.[24] The desktop client uses
> GUI toolkits such as wxWidgets and
> Cocoa. Other notable Python libraries
> include Twisted, ctypes, and pywin32.

Answer (score 0):

and also just for fun: Twister, Blister and Klister

Answer (score 0):

Python оказался востребован даже в сфере ML(машинного обучения) и для написания кода,исполняемого на квантовых компьютерах.
Популярность в 2019-м настолько велика, что отдельные аналитики называют его языком программирования номер один в 2019-м году.

P.S.Есть такая школа для одаренных детей в столице Казахстана, в которой Python изучают с 11 лет. Не говоря о том,  что во многих университетах США Python  выбран в качестве базового ЯП для обучения программированию.